# Save data using pivot table

Tags: laravel

I want to save data for all user that have certain group_id in new table.

[image: pivot table]

For example, i want to save new data to all user who have `group_id = 1`, but based on my code it only save `user_id = 2`. It should save `user_id = 1` too.

```
$group = Group::find($req->groupID);
foreach($group->creators as $creator)
$attend = new Attendance;
$attend->groupID = $req->groupID;
$attend->meetingID = $data->id;
$attend->userFeedback = NULL;
$attend->userAttendance = 'Not Attend';

$attend->userID = $creator->id;
$attend->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run your loop properly. Follow the below code

```
$group = Group::find($req->groupID);
foreach($group->creators as $creator) 
{
    $attend = new Attendance();
    $attend->groupID = $req->groupID;
    $attend->meetingID = $data->id;
    $attend->userFeedback = NULL;
    $attend->userAttendance = 'Not Attend';

    $attend->userID = $creator->id;
    $attend->save();
}
```